# Save Session Spot In Cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm making a story-driven app in Cordova. The problem is that whenever the app relaunches, it restarts the entire story. Is there a way I can set it so as long as the app isn't deleted it saves the exact progress? I haven't found anything online...

Answer (score 0):

Because your Cordova app runs in the browser, you can use browser storage technologies like LocalStorage (basic kind of storage), WebSQL or even the newer IndexedDB. What I personally like to do is to use an abstraction layer like PouchDB (for offline syncing) or localForage.

If you choose to go the WebSQL way and want to store lots of data, consider Cordova plugins for WebSQL.

Comment: I'm testing it out on my phone though... @Bouzmine

Comment: @Owen I don't understand what you mean, if you're using Cordova, your app is running in a web browser.

Comment: I ran a build and are running it off of Xcode which is return is running on my phone @Bouzmine

Comment: @Owen, Cordova is just building a web app (like a web page) then wrapping it. You can use *most* web technologies in your code, just as you would on a browser.